# ROS2 Foxy - Arduino Best Practice?

Tags: arduino, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Howdo,

TLDR:  What is the best practice in ROS2 to send and received messages on an Arduino/Teensy please?

I've been building a robot and I've been using ROS1 in a very naive way to send messages from a custom controller, I'm using a Teensy on the controller to monitor the state of physical switches and joysticks and on the robot to translate between servos and sensors.  I've been using ros-serial and -arduino for this.  On both sides the microcontrollers are connected to a Raspberry Pi.

I've decided to switch to ROS2 as my knowledge of ROS is still basic and I figure it would give me a head start on learning the new architecture.  Had a bit of a play and very impressed with the multicasting!

The one sticking point is getting communications between the Teensy board and ROS2, is there a best practice for this with Foxy please?  I've been researching my options and it seems like there isn't consensus on this at the minute.  Is the best bet at the minute to have a custom node on the Pi translating or is there some option I've missed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354329/ros2-foxy---arduino-best-practice?/) by [kneave](https://answers.ros.org/users/55611/kneave/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2020-06-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following up on my research on this it seems there isn't currently a best practice however these are the most common solutions, micro-ros support for Teensy has recently been added but early in development at the minute:

1. ROS1 to ROS2 bridge and use ros-serial/ros-arduino
2. Use one of the soloutions listed on this [page](https://github.com/osrf/ros2_serial_example)
3. Use an Open CR or Teensy and [this](https://www.hackster.io/news/micro-ros-project-brings-ros-2-to-the-arduino-ide-and-cli-through-an-experimental-library-release-656a72fff2fa) library.

ros2arduino seems like the best fit however it isn't currently listed as running with Foxy.  I'm going to go with option 1 for now, I have existing code that runs on ROS1 that I can use for communicating with an Arduino.

Edit to add micro-ros update.

---

Originally posted by [kneave](https://answers.ros.org/users/55611/kneave/) with karma: 96 on 2020-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TheMilkman92](https://answers.ros.org/users/60334/themilkman92/) on 2020-11-04**:
Hey, just wondering how you went with this? Looking into doing something very similar, but with a Arduino mega.

**Comment by [kneave](https://answers.ros.org/users/55611/kneave/) on 2020-11-07**:
I've not got any further to be honest but the 3rd item is the most promising, it's only for OpenCR or the Teensy though.  The Teensy 4.1 could be an option if you are able to swap that for the Mega?

**Comment by [TheMilkman92](https://answers.ros.org/users/60334/themilkman92/) on 2020-11-19**:
Yeah I tried to get all 3 of those working aswell. Decided to go back to Kinetic for now, but will try teensy and foxy in a later version

**Comment by [kathan_patel](https://answers.ros.org/users/77031/kathan_patel/) on 2021-07-02**:
i was in same thing but i just want to know how to make the bridge as i tried the bridge but the topic which is publishing the data is not seen in ros 2 please help..

**Comment by [kneave](https://answers.ros.org/users/55611/kneave/) on 2021-07-20**:
Hi Kathan, you need to start a new question for that, it'll mean the most people possible will see and be able to help.